# Could not find method compile() for arguments ... nativescript and nativescript-aws

Tags: android, nativescript, aws-sdk, tns

I am rather new to nativescript and cannot wrap my head around what I am doing wrong, I come across this error message when trying to build an app using `tns run android`. This is the full error message:

```
Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.16] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

After spending hours researching the reason for that error, I found that most answers were recommending to change `compile` to `implementation`. this isn't something I can do as the build.gradle file is created only when running the command `tns run android`.

I am running `nativescript 8.0.4`

My version of `tns-android` in my `package.json` is 6.5.3 and `nativescript-aws-sdk` is 0.0.4, the of version `tns-anandroid` seems to be using gradle pluggin version 5.4.1, as per the `gradle-wrapper.properties` inside the `tns-android`'s `node_modules` folder. see bellow:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

When running the `tns run android` two folders are created inside the `platforms` folder as expected

```
platforms
|__android
|__tempPlugin
   |__nativescript_aws_sdk
```

The version is fine in `platforms/android`
with the following `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

I The error originates from `platforms/tempPlugin/nativescript_aws_sdk/build.gradle` upon checking the `gradle-wrapper.properties` the version shows gradle pluggin version 5.4.1:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
```

I am aware that `compile` has been removed from gradle from v7.

Things I've tried this far:

- changed versions of nativescript
- change versions of tns-android
- remove tns-android and replace with @nativescript/android

What is the walk around this problem?

Comment: I think the best thing would be to upgrade to @nativescript/android, tns-android is quite old.  To help with the migration I recommend you enter the NS discord community https://discord.gg/nativescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nativescript-aws-sdk` plugin(https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-aws-sdk) uses old deprecated compile gradle keyword in its `include.gradle` (as of now https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-aws-sdk/commit/9901b611ebd620c166bfabebb9f136e8fa07597d)

In `node_modules/nativescript-aws-sdk/platforms/android/include.gradle` replace:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.16'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.16'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.16'
}
```

with

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.16'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.16'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.16'
}
```